# Enabling Windows 10 Kiosk mode using Embedded Shell Launcher

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, launcher, kiosk

We are developing a C# Windows application that needs to be run on Windows 10 Pro in Kiosk mode. The goal is to limit the possibilities for the user to only be able to use our Application.

I have tried following this guide from MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher

And this guide from technet:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions

But without success...

We start by installing the Embedded Shell Launcher from Programs and Features (Even tried the commandline install as well)

Then fetch the large powershell script - and modify it to use our own user and path for the application to start.

When we run the script it actually stops right in the start with the following message:

```
WARNING: The generated type is not public.

Shell Launcher license enabled is set to False

This device doesn't have required license to use Shell Launcher
```

So it seems that I do not have the licence required? Enabled?

Strange... If i uncomment this startup check i get through the script and in the end the scripts says Enabled = true and then Enabled = false?

Strange so it seems the script ends with disabling the hole lot again.

If I uncomment this last disable and reboot - I get black screen right after login. So something is going on.

But until now I haven't had success starting the Kiosk application.

Anybody having success with this tools? Guides?

Help is much appriciated

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using? Shell Launcher requires Enterprise or Education. Not using one of those might be why you are getting a license warning.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting.... Now reading through the second guide again I think that you are exactly correct...

This is the text:
A single-use or kiosk device is easy to set up in Windows 10 for desktop editions (Pro, Enterprise, and Education). For a kiosk device to run a Universal Windows app, use the assigned access feature. For a kiosk device (Windows 10 Enterprise or Education) to run a Classic Windows application, use Shell Launcher to set a custom user interface as the shell. To return the device to the regular shell, see Sign out of assigned access.

So is Enterprice really needed?

Comment: To use Embedded Shell Launcher, yes you need to be using an Enterprise or Education SKU. But you could always do the trick of changing the shell in the registry to your exe. Otherwise there are third party products to do this. Reg key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`

Comment: Yes I know about the Winlogon\Shell option and have used this before. I wanted to try and see if the Shell Launcher was more secure and so forth. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41979285/2771556