# UWP App in Assigned Access and Windows Store for Business - what happens when an app update is available?

Tags: windows, uwp, kiosk, kiosk-mode, windows-dev-center

Junior Dev here trying to figure out how to deploy and manage a UWP app for multiple Assigned Access accounts (think restaurant kiosks) that I won't be able to physically access or have a user interact with them for updates.

**Question:** If I had a UWP app on Windows Store for Business with a pending update, what happens when the app is currently running on an Assigned Access account?

1. When does the app actually get updated? On the next reboot of the machine before the app is launched via Assigned Access?
2. Is there a way to force the app to update and restart without a
   reboot  of the machine?
3. Is there any user interaction required for this to happen (like a
   UAC prompt)
4. Does the AUMID change and if so does this break the assigned access?

Thanks for all you help!

Comment: I recommend to use shell replacing for kiosk mode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41979285/2771556

Answer (score 1):

> 1. When does the app actually get updated? On the next reboot of the
>      machine before the app is launched via Assigned Access?

No, users cannot update the app via Assigned Access. So you need to log out of the kiosk-mode to update the app.

> 2.Is there a way to force the app to update and restart without a reboot
>   of the machine?

No. And since currently for UWP app, we need to log out of the Assigned Access account and sign in with non-kiosk account so we cannot avoid a reboot of the machine.

> 3.Is there any user interaction required for this to happen (like a UAC prompt)

As I said above, you can switch with your non-kiosk account to complete the update and switch back to the Assigned Access account if needed.

> 4.Does the AUMID change and if so does this break the assigned access?

Yes. "AUMID" depends on the application and current user of the machine. So if one of them changes, the assigned access will be broken.

Comment: And this is the reason UWP is still not moving as fast as Microsoft would like. Two years on from this answer, there is still no way to update a LoB app deployed via assigned access.