# Turn on/off kiosk mode for application regarding user privileges

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-7, kiosk-mode

I have a winforms application written in C++/CLI running on Windows 7. Within the application the user can log in as normal user or administrator. As normal user the app should run in kiosk mode, no access to the explorer, no task manager etc.. If changed to administrator, the user regain access and the kiosk mode should be deactivated.

I can figure out how to run my application as shell, but how can i change this during application runtime without restarting windows?

In addition i read something about changing the GPO to set my application into kiosk mode. Is it maybe possible to save and load different GPO's at runtime without restarting?

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal I'm used 2 accounts: "Admin" and "Kiosk", then in the application I added password protected feature for log out to lock screen. Kiosk mode configuration you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41979285/2771556

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i cant change the windows user. There can only be one instance of the software running. I have a user manager in my software and want to start/stop the kiosk mode at runtime.

Comment: I didn't say about several instances. For switching in runtime - just use full-screen mode with the topmost flag.

Comment: So keep the explorer as shell and just set the software in fullscreen? Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Also, you can kill explorer, but in this case, you also kill all opened explorer windows - this will not be good for the user. And explorer start will take some additional time and can produce some unexpected bugs. The safest solution - full-screen and topmost flag.