# windows 10 "kiosk mode" - local web server and browser

Tags: windows-10, webserver, kiosk

I'm trying to build a "kiosk" type system using windows 10 and a big touch display. I have some WordPress content I'd like to display in a browser. I need to run the browser locally, as I'm without an internet connection for now, so I have installed xammpp and a wordpress module.

I have tried a few options such as an assigned access account, but I cant run the webserver there.

I have also tried to create a provisioning package to install the server and browser etc but installing this overwrote my existing administrator account and locked me out so I had to wipe everything and start from scratch.

Ideally I would like an admin account and a kiosk account with just the browser (any browser is fine) which can access localhost. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are a number of off-the-shelf solutions out on the market that lock down the Windows environment (Google for Windows kiosk software.) I'd explore one of those, since there are many ways that someone can escape your application. I'd couple that with a local install of IIS if you need server-side logic like ASP.net or PHP. If you don't, and it's just straight HTML/JS/CSS, you could just host it on the filesystem. (Full disclosure: my company makes one of those software solutions.)

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding this but imo you just have to set your webserver to run as a service under system account and not start it manually and it will run even when logged in with the assigned access account.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Syberdoor, great tip, I set the webserver to run as a service which helped a lot. Assigned access in windows is very limited with web browsers so i ended up writing a small logon script in a local user account to open chrome in kiosk mode and then log out if you exit. Seems to be working well at the moment. Will add script when i'm done with this project

Comment: Here is full solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938422/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-program-in-kiosk-mode/41979285#41979285