# C# - How to Close a From and Application.Run

Tags: c#, forms, formclosing

This simple code prevent application from closing

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread TH = new Thread(Run);
        TH.Start();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        Application.Run();
    }
```

On the other hand i can stop this with:

```
        Application.Exit();
```

But, this does not work with when [X] button on Form is pressed, the Debugging still working, and the <strike>console</strike> debug output gives me this, while Form is actually closed:

```
The thread 0x65c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x11c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Any Idea how to actually stop this totally with [X] button?

Comment: Are you actually asking [How to run a C# program in kiosk mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41938422/205233)?

Comment: I did not actuall got your point, as this application needs to be started when users needs it, just like notepad. But when Thread run Application.Run. application still works without form, after closing it. I tried to handle this with Form_Closing, but it does not work. Only thing that is working is Application.Exit(), but this cannot be executed with X button on form

Comment: `TH.IsBackground = true;`

Comment: Oh you've found a workaround. Ok. Please keep a note on the `IsBackground` property of the `Thread` object. You will need it one day.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to fix it.

in **Form1.Designer.cs** inside `InitializeComponent()`

this needs to be added

```
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_Closing);
```

then in **Form1.cs**

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```