# Run an app on startup that opens a browser with my url and dont let the user close the browser or App

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to create a c# script for my clients that opens chrome browser on startup with a specific URL and the user shouldn't be able to close or minimize that specific window.

even if the user closes, the application should restart.

How can I do this?

I have created half of it with chromium widget in my form screen and use the following code

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Browser1.Load("https://app.digitalsignage-templates.com/screen/f230b8b7-ed53-4401-a50d-1a7a8281fac2");
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Browser1.Load("https://app.digitalsignage-templates.com/screen/f230b8b7-ed53-4401-a50d-1a7a8281fac2");
   

}
```

But how do I restart the app when I close the broswer? When I use Application.Restart, it throws an error "application was not started by this process,so cannot interfere".

What can I do?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for windows kiosk mode, no programming required.

Comment: [Here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41979285/1270789), assuming you mean Windows 10.

Comment: But in kiosk, the user can close the app right? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @KenY-N I wouldnt have access to the clients computer,so setting kiosk user would be a problem right?

Comment: @Jerin Cherian, you can try to disable your close button in your chrome browser by using  winapi EnableMenuItem. You can refer to the link [C# disable close button on windows form application](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b1f0d913-c603-43e9-8fe3-681fb7286d4c/c-disable-close-button-on-windows-form-application?forum=csharpgeneral#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20disable%20the,%2C%20SC_CLOSE%2C%20MF_BYCOMMAND%20%7C%20MF_DISABLED%20)%3B).

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I have diabled the close button,but he can still close the app using the other methods right? is there a way to listen to the event of browser closing and restart the broswer?

Comment: @Jerin Cherian, is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my further attempt, you can use WMI to listen the browser closing event and restart the browser.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
            startWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(startWatch_EventArrived);
            startWatch.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("successfully start");
            ManagementEventWatcher stopWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"));
            stopWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(stopWatch_EventArrived);
            stopWatch.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
            startWatch.Stop();
            stopWatch.Stop();
        }

        static void stopWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString();
            Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            if (name == "chrome.exe" && p.Length == 0)
            {
                Process.Start(name, "https://www.google.com.hk/");
            }
        }

        static void startWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString();
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessId"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Process started: {0}", name);
           
        }
```

After I run the above code, it will restart the chrome browser with url google if I close the current chrome.

Besides, you need to **run as administrator** about the above code, otherwise you will get the error.(Right-click-vs2019-More-Run as administrator).